# Fatal Error: Steam needs to be online to update <?> Please confrm your network connection and try again

Tags: debian, steam

I am trying to install steam on my laptop and keep getting this error.

I have installed steam by the Debian repo which ran fine but when I run it from the command line or the menu I get the following error.

```
Fatal Error: Steam needs to be online to update <?> Please confirm your network connection and try again.
```

When running it from the command I get this output:

```
WARNING: setlocale('en_US.UTF-8') failed, using locale: 'C'. International characters may not work.
[2022-02-17 09:38:18] Startup - updater built Nov 22 2021 22:06:59
ILocalize::AddFile() failed to load file "public/steambootstrapper_english.txt".
[2022-02-17 09:38:18] Failed to load cached hosts file (File 'update_hosts_cached.vdf' not found), using defaults
[2022-02-17 09:38:18] Using the following download hosts for Public, Realm steamglobal
[2022-02-17 09:38:18] 1. http://media.steampowered.com, /client/, Realm 'steamglobal', weight was 1, source = 'baked in'
[2022-02-17 09:38:18] Verifying installation...
[2022-02-17 09:38:18] Unable to read and verify install manifest /home/wakey/.steam/debian-installation/package/steam_client_ubuntu12.installed
[2022-02-17 09:38:18] Verification complete
[2022-02-17 09:38:18] Downloading Update...
[2022-02-17 09:38:18] Checking for available update...
[2022-02-17 09:38:18] Downloading manifest: http://media.steampowered.com/client/steam_client_ubuntu12
[2022-02-17 09:38:18] Download failed: http error 0 (media.steampowered.com/client/steam_client_ubuntu12)
[2022-02-17 09:38:18] DownloadManifest - exhausted list of download hosts
[2022-02-17 09:38:18] failed to load manifest from buffer.
[2022-02-17 09:38:18] Failed to load manifest
[2022-02-17 09:38:18] Error: Download failed: http error 0
[2022-02-17 09:38:18] Saving metrics to disk (/home/wakey/.steam/debian-installation/package/steam_client_metrics.bin)
[2022-02-17 09:38:18] Error: Steam needs to be online to update.         Please confirm your network connection and try again.
[2022-02-17 09:38:20] Shutdown
src/tier0/threadtools.cpp (3594) : Assertion Failed: Illegal termination of worker thread 'Thread(0x0x585812f0/0x0xebe7da'
src/tier0/threadtools.cpp (3594) : Assertion Failed: Illegal termination of worker thread 'Thread(0x0x585812f0/0x0xebe7da'
cat: '/home/wakey/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime.tar.xz.part*': No such file or directory
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
xz: (stdin): File format not recognized
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

There are some comments online in forums about this where I need to change my /etc/hosts to include new IPs for the client

```
ping media.steampowered.com                                                                                                                                2 ⨯
PING a1843.b.akamai.net (**213.123.255.80**) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

i then add that to my etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 view-localhost
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       Laptop
10.10.11.125    backdoor.htb
10.10.11.124    shibboleth.htb
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts

208.64.200.7 client-download.steampowered.com
162.254.192.17  client-download.steampowered.com
213.123.255.80  media.steampowered.com
```

But i still get the same error

Comment: `http://media.steampowered.com/client/steam_client_ubuntu12` exists and appears to download a 4KB json file for me. What do you get if you try to go to that location in a browser? You might need to remove the lines from your hosts file to get an honest view of it. Are you behind some kind of firewall or VPN? Do you need or use a proxy to connect to the internet?

Comment: I get a download prompt so i can access it manually via firefox.  I am not behind any VPN or a Proxy.